# Equivalent "Show Logical Structure" from Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

The code I am currently working on is running into a problem that seems to only get fixed when I disable the Show Logical Structure button in Eclipse. However, I prefer to work in Intellij, is there an equivalent way to disable this in Intellij so I can continue working in this IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is called **Enable alternative view for Collection classes**, try disabling it:

[image: debugger]